# Possible to change background-color onClick, then automatically change back a second later?

Tags: javascript, jquery, background, jquery-animate

Noob here - I'm working on a simple Javascript calculator, and I'm using lists (li) for buttons. I want the li background-color to change onClick, but then automatically change back half a second later. So basically I want the button click to flash the new color, not toggle it.

Is this possible?

Edit: This is what I have in my header now, but it's still not working:

```
$(li).click(function() {
    var $elem = $(this);
    var oldBG = $elem.css('backgroundColor'));
    $elem.css('backgroundColor', '#FFFFFF').delay(1000).css('backgroundColor', oldBG);
});
```

and my li tags:

```
<li class="key" onClick="calc('7')">7</li>
```

Comment: are you using jquery or plain plain javascript? Also post sample code to understand your issue better.

Comment: I am using plain javascript for the calculator, but I linked the jQuery framework in my header, so that should let me them both right? Sorry, I don't have any sample code - I'm trying to write it now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('.key').click(function() {
  // make a jQ collection of the DOM element from the event
  var $elem = $(this);
  // store the background-color
  var oldBG = $elem.css('background-color');
  // change the background color to what you want
  $elem.css('backgroundColor', '#FF0000');
  // after 1 second, change it back
  setTimeout(function() {
    $elem.css('background-color', oldBG);
  }, 1000);
});
```

[working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/uNQgs/)

jQuery-UI will animate color values using the jquery-color plugin, if you're into that

Comment: @Dan Isn't it 'background-color' instead of 'backgrounColor' ?

Comment: css attribute is background-color - jquery can use both, but for an object it takes backgroundColor (cause you can't have hiphens in object names).. so either works.

Comment: That code makes a ton of sense, but it's not working! This is how I modified it:

[edit: see code in my original post]

I'm not sure why it doesn't work. My li class is "key", but I've also got a separate onClick function inside the li brackets. Could that be causing some interference?

Comment: My bad on the delay function - it was going from red to oldBG with no delay. Revised the code and updated the answer

Comment: Dan, that's awesome work. It's still not working for me, but since that Fiddle works, I'm sure the problem is with my code. I'll work it out, but thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Sure is possible!

Check out the documentation for setTimeout()

Here's a link to get you started.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: Thanks very much for the link, I'll read through it and try my luck. Somebody please upvote Keith on my behalf.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to change your markup so that each button is an <a> element (perhaps inside those li elements), you can use

```
a:active {
```

To change the way the buttons look when pressed.
http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can add a background color style to the element when clicked, and use the `setTimeout` function to remove it later:

```
$(function(){
  $('li').click(function(){
    var e = $(this);
    e.css('background-color', 'red');
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      e.css('background-color', '');
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

(Note: There is a `delay` method in jQquery, but that is intended to be used with animation, not as a replacement for `setTimeout`.)

Working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="sv" xml:lang="sv">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
  $('li').click(function(){
    var e = $(this);
    e.css('background-color', 'red');
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      e.css('background-color', '');
    }, 500);
  });
});

function calc(digit) {
    var lcd = $('#lcd');
    lcd.text(lcd.text() + digit);
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="lcd"></div>

<ul>
  <li class="key" onClick="calc('1')">1</li>
  <li class="key" onClick="calc('2')">2</li>
  <li class="key" onClick="calc('3')">3</li>
  <li class="key" onClick="calc('4')">4</li>
  <li class="key" onClick="calc('5')">5</li>
  <li class="key" onClick="calc('6')">6</li>
  <li class="key" onClick="calc('7')">7</li>
  <li class="key" onClick="calc('8')">8</li>
  <li class="key" onClick="calc('9')">9</li>
  <li class="key" onClick="calc('0')">0</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Right, so I used your code but it's not working. What am I doing wrong, do you think? Your code makes sense. My li tag looks like this: <li class="key" onClick="calc('7')">7</li>, then I have your code in script tags in the header. onClick Conflict, maybe?

Comment: @yatman: I don't know why it fails in your code. I tried the code with your tag in Firefox 3.6.3 and Internet Explorer 8, and it works just fine. Both the calc function and the jQuery event handler is called. I added a working example above.